# Implement Java Interface with Raw type from Scala

Tags: java, scala, generics, sonarqube, scala-java-interop

I'm trying to build an extension for Sonar, using Scala.
I need to extend the following Java interface:

```
public interface Decorator extends BatchExtension, CheckProject {
    void decorate(Resource resource, DecoratorContext context);
}
```

but **Resource** type is actually defined like:

```
public abstract class Resource<PARENT extends Resource>
```

I know I can workaround creating a Java raw super-class.
I'd like to stick to Scala-only, also know if there's a solution I'm missing, and whether there's an improvement I could suggest to SonarSource people to make on their side (on using raw types).

I've read there were issues with this, and some workarounds for some cases, but none seemed to apply here ([a workaround](http://michid.wordpress.com/2009/08/30/implementing-java-interfaces-and-generics/), [an apparently fixed ticket](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-1737), also there's ticket 2091...)

Comment: This is a really good question! I tried playing around with it and was able to get some error messages that appear inaccurate. `Resource[_]` seems like it should work, but it doesn't for some reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some trial and error and looking at the error messages, I came up with this which compiles:

```
import org.sonar.api.batch._
import org.sonar.api.resources._ 

object D {
  type R = Resource[T] forSome {type T <: Resource[_ <: AnyRef]}
  type S[T] = Resource[T] forSome {type T <: Resource[_ <: AnyRef]}
}

class D extends Decorator {
  def decorate(r: D.R, context: DecoratorContext) {}
  //def decorate(r: D.S[_], context: DecoratorContext) {} // compiles too
  def shouldExecuteOnProject(project: Project) = true
}
```

I'm not sure whether it will allow you to implement what you need. I looked at [Resource](http://docs.sonarsource.org/2.2/apidocs/org/sonar/api/resources/Resource.html), and it could represent `File` which extends `Resource<Directory>` or sometimes be an erased (raw?) type that just extends `Resource` like for `Directory`.

Edit: thinking about it some more, the `forSome` can be eliminated - this compiles too:

```
def decorate(resource: Resource[_ <: Resource[_ <: AnyRef]],
             context: DecoratorContext) {
}
```

Comment: huynhjl, you're the man! I really thought there was no way around this. I think these solutions for scala-java interop should be documented somewhere.

Comment: @Roman, true, I remember stumbling myself on an even simpler issue trying to implement `SolrRequestHandler`. I am curious, where did you try to look at this type of information while trying to solve your problem? I have my idea where I would add this info, but it won't do good if this isn't where people go look for it.

Comment: I did my first search here. For sure it would be nice to have a **Java/Scala interop** entry at docs.scala-lang.org, don't you think?

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea about an answer, but if I write

```
def decorate(r: Resource[Resource[_]])
```

I get an error

> `type arguments [Resource[_]] do not conform to class Resource's type parameter bounds [PARENT <: Resource[_ <: AnyRef]]`

Which seems wrong to me, because I would think the actual type bounds should be more like `Resource[_ <: Resource[_ <: Resource[...     ...]]` (`AnyRef` wouldn't be appropriate as an upper bound).