# Scala: how to implement a java interface that contains scala "typed" classes without their type parameters

Tags: java, scala, scala-java-interop

This is a tricky one - I have a java interface that I want to implement in scala:

```
public interface Foo {
  public void bar(scala.Array arr);
}
```

Is it even possible to implement in scala? when I try:

```
class FooImpl extends Foo {
  override def bar(arr: Array[_]): Unit = ???
}
```

I get:

```
Error:(13, 7) class FooImpl needs to be abstract, since method bar 
in trait Foo of type (x$1: Array)Unit is not defined
(Note that Array does not match Array[_]. To implement a raw type, use 
Array[_])
class FooImpl extends Foo {
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message is giving you the answer for any generic type other than `Array` (after replacing the name, of course):

> To implement a raw type, use `Array[_]`

"Raw type" is what Java calls a generic type used without a type parameter and e.g. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html explains why you should not use them except to interface with now horribly obsolete pre-Java-5 code. So if it is at all an option, you should fix the Java interface in the first place.

Now, why does this not work for `Array`? It's a special type, which is really built into compiler. Its instances are real JVM arrays, which don't have a common type in Java. So when it's used in Scala code, the compiled bytecode doesn't use `scala.Array` at all. I guess that it only exists as a JVM type (unlike e.g. `scala.Any` or `scala.Null`) to put the static methods there, but all instance methods are defined as `throw new Error()`. It seems the error message didn't take this unique case into account.

So, the answer is: no, it can't be implemented in Scala, as far as I am aware. But it can't be non-trivially implemented in Java either. And even for trivial implementations, you'd run into the same issues when trying to write code *using* it.

Comment: I can't change the interface's code, so it's not an option.

Comment: as far as I understand scala.Array is just an example, it doesn't work with any rawTyped scala class.

Comment: No, for other types it should work, as the error message says. Though see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10875130/implement-java-interface-with-raw-type-from-scala if the generic type has bounds.

Answer (score 0):

To make the code work you either have to

- Make the `FooImpl` declaration as `abstract` class
- Implement the `bar` method

because "Java interfaces don’t implement behaviour".

For your reference see [this](https://alvinalexander.com/scala/how-to-extend-java-interfaces-like-scala-traits) page.

Comment: The question is _how_ it's possible to implement `bar`.